# Text in my table is not well formatted

Tags: xltabular

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}\usepackage{amsthm}
\geometry{a4paper, top = 2cm, right = 2cm, left = 2cm, bottom = 2cm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell, xltabular}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begingroup
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\makegapedcells
\def\arraystretch{1.2}
%\newcommand\mcl[1]{\multicolumn{3}{l|}{#1}}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|l|L|L|l|}
\begin{document}

    
    \caption{Analisi di coerenza dei colori}\label{Tab:analisi-coerenza-colori}\\
    \endfirsthead
    \caption*{Tabella \ref{Tab:analisi-coerenza-colori}: Analisi di coerenza dei colori}\\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{r}{\emph{Continua alla pagina successiva}}
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot
    
    \hline
    Obiettivo & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Valutare la coerenza dei colori utilizzati nell'applicazione rispetto al loro significato psicologico} \\
    
    \hline
    & Colore & Significato psicologico &  Significato effettivo nell'app \\  
    \cline{2-4} & {Verde}  & {Natura, ambiente ecologico, generatività, benessere, fiducia, pace, respiro, interiorità, vita, vegetazione, gioventù, equilibrante, neutro nello spettro visivo} & {Colore principale dell'applicazione il quale non deve essere troppo aggressivo per la vista dell'utente} \\
    
    \hline
    
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

This is my table. Unfortunately when I fill the last column the text is not well formatted.

[image]

- How can I fix?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ, which table-related packages you employ (so that others may compile the code you posted), and how the `L` column type is defined.

Comment: I have edited my post @Mico

Comment: No, please make this into a full self contained example that others can copy and test as is. Here we have to add document and preamble and our choice might not match yours. So please provide code that can be tested as is.

Comment: I have just Edited @daleif

Comment: Please make sure your example actually compiles. Are you by any change using overleaf? As many overlook the red button when there are compilation errors.

Comment: The right most column probably should be an `L` column as well and you need to deal with the `multicolumn` in the `Obiettivo` line.